# can't find Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundler, dreamhost

I'm trying to get bundler working on my Dreamhost account. when I type bundle update in my application I get

> -bash: bundle: command not found

I installed bundler 1.0.15 in gem bundler

`gem environment` results in:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2008-08-11 patchlevel 72) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /home/tarscher/gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /home/tarscher/gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /home/tarscher/gems
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gempath" => ["/home/tarscher/gems", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
     - "gemhome" => "/home/tarscher/gems"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

I configured my  .bashrc

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin;/home/myuser/gems/bin
```

and my .gemrc

```
gemhome: /home/myuser/gems
gempath:
- /home/tarscher/gems
- /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

**UPDATE**
When I go into `/home/myuser/gems/bin`where the bundle script is located dir and type bundle I also get `-bash: bundle: command not found` .

Someone knows why bundler isn't found?

Thanks

Comment: # ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin;/home/myuser/gems/bin;/usr/bin

doesn't solve the error

Comment: What if you add `/home/tarscher/gems/bin` to the PATH?

Comment: thats the myuser but removed it for security reasons in Stackoverflow :)

Comment: what's the output of `echo $PATH` though? The `.bashrc` doesn't get executed unless it's a non-login shell, but it sounds like you're logged in.

Comment: I was able to solve it by adding the bundle script to the home/myuser/.gems/bin dir .

Comment: When you type `gem list | grep bundler` do you see bundler?

Answer (score 1):

There's an error here:

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/bin;/home/myuser/gems/bin
```

The paths must be separated by `:`, not `;`

Comment: Thx for the update but I still get the error. I updated my question